# How to get each data in each row C# & SQL

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Let's say I have a table with 3 columns like this:

```
ID | NAME | Subject
---+------+----------
 1 | Mark | English
 1 | Mark | Math
 2 | Matt | Math
 2 | Matt | English
 1 | Mark | History
```

How to get each subject of "Mark" like English, Math, History (order by) that will match to their id in every row in column subject? Because I only get the first subject which is "English" or the first row.

```
string sql = "select * from tbl_Student where ID like '"+ID.Text+"'";

cm = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
dr = cm.ExecuteReader();

while (dr.Read())
{
    Subject1.Text = dr["Subject"].ToString();
    Subject2.Text = dr["Subject"].ToString();
    Subject3.Text = dr["Subject"].ToString();
}

dr.Close();
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want an object containing 'English', 'Math', 'History'?

Comment: What happens if you have more subjects for a student? Do you have a lot of text boxes, like `Subject1`, `Subject2`, ..., `Subject10`, etc. ?

Comment: Yes sir i edit it. my bad. check it again.

Answer (score 3):

You replace the value of `Subject.Text` in each loop. That means it contains only the last value.

You should concatenate the string

```
Subject.Text += dr["Subject"].ToString();
```

Comment: Sir i edit my question please check it again Thankyou! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely change the like operator to an equal(=) operator.
And you are having always one value in the loop, concatenate the strings.

Comment: Sir i edit my question please check it again Thankyou! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

while (dr.Read())
{
    sb.Append(dr["Subject"].ToString());
    sb.Append(",");

}

result = sb.ToString().TrimEnd(',');
```

### UPDATE

use `switch/case` then, to determine your id and assign its value to proper `TextBox`:

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    string subject = dr["Subject"].ToString();
    switch (dr["ID"].ToString()) 
    {
        case "1":
            Subject1.Text += subject + " ";//$"{subject} "; //or use string builder as I've showed above 
            break;
        case "2":
            Subject2.Text += subject + " ";//$"{subject} ";
            break;
        case "3":
            Subject3.Text += subject + " ";//$"{subject} ";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Also, please use **[Parameterized Queries](https://www.google.com/search?q=parametrized+queries+sql&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab)**.

Comment: Sir i edit my question please check it again Thankyou! :)

Comment: I got this error sir in,
string subject = dr.Field<string>("Subject"); 
"does not contain a definition for 'Field' and the best extension method overload 'System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field<T>( System.Data.DataRow, int) has some invalid arguments"

Comment: @user6767011 Edited, sorry I forgot that you were using data reader.

Comment: sir last thing, "; expected","invalid term", "only assignment,call,increment,decrement, and new object expression can be use as statement", "Unexpected character $" in Subject1.Text += $"{subject}"; Thankyou in advance sir!

Comment: @user6767011 check one more time.

Comment: i remove this $ sign and all errors gone but it didn't show to my Subject1-3.Text

Comment: This is just a sample, you need to correct `ID`'s in `case`es according to your table.